# How can I add items to the indicator-session menu?

Tags: indicator, configuration, menu, customization

Is it possible to add to or edit the Session Indicator menu items?

Is there an easy way to do this, or would it involve recompiling a custom build?

I cannot find much relating to this online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some refs:
 - [jimi312 / Titlebar Menu / source — Bitbucket:](https://bitbucket.org/jimi312/titlebar-menu/src/31ca1c031412/com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar.xml)
 - [Programming with DBus using PyQt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148366/programming-with-dbus-using-pyqt)
 - [Unity/QA/StateIntrospection - Ubuntu Wiki:](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/QA/StateIntrospection) especially example code

At the moment passive querying can extract information such as shown in this post:
[How does one find out which application is associated with an indicator icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185991/how-does-one-find-out-which-application-is-associated-with-an-indicator-icon) .

I am also exploring the answer to this question as it relates to DBus, to use as high a level interface as possible to avoid low level programming.  The ultimate objective is to create a utility that minimally identifies the host applications of the indicators and the sub-apps of their component menus. Maximally it would allow modifications to the menus such as the `session-indicator` menu including the top level menu, ie. the icon indicator of the unity-panel itself.

It would be good to know which, (if any!) modifier methods exist in the DBus environment to modify the DBus, so the `indicator panel` and it's components, such as `Session Indicator`, could be modified as you require.

The following commands reveal the interface methods to manipulate the `session indicator` bus information but unfortunately the parameters used in these methods are not described here - the reference above supplies links to the documents describing the general indicator interfacing - but specifics for the `session indicator` are still needed.

The output from

```
qdbus --session  com.canonical.indicator.session
```

implicates the existence of menu interfaces as the **items** below:

> /
>   /org
>   /org/ayatana
>   /org/ayatana/indicator
>   /org/ayatana/indicator/service
>   /com
>   /com/canonical
>   /com/canonical/indicator
>   /com/canonical/indicator/users
>   **/com/canonical/indicator/users/menu**
>   /com/canonical/indicator/session
>   /com/canonical/indicator/session/service
>   **/com/canonical/indicator/session/menu**

The interfaces can be examined with:

```
gdbus introspect --session --dest com.canonical.indicator.session \
                 --object-path /com/canonical/indicator/users/menu --recurse
```

and

```
gdbus introspect --session --dest com.canonical.indicator.session \
                 --object-path /com/canonical/indicator/session/menu --recurse
```

Note the internal reference to `interface com.canonical.dbusmenu`.

For a real comprehensive dump use:

```
gdbus introspect --session --dest com.canonical.indicator.session --object-path / --recurse
```

Several sub-apps are bound to the `session indicator` drop down menu but what is not clear is whether these interface methods just transfer data to the associated sub-menu apps or whether in fact there is a communication channel to the session indicator app itself so its menu can be "methodized".

Also,

```
qdbus --literal --session  com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar           \
                          /com/canonical/AppMenu/Registrar           \
                           com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar.GetMenus  \
| sed -e 's/], \[/],\n[/g' | sort -k 4 -V
```

provides a list of interface menu associations (there are `menus`for the windows and also for the indicators like the `session indicator`, which is which in the list below still needs determination)

```
[Argument: (uso) 25167301, ":1.22", [ObjectPath: /com/canonical/menu/18005C5]],
[Argument: (uso) 25165828, ":1.22", [ObjectPath: /com/canonical/menu/1800004]],
[Argument: (uso) 48234500, ":1.81", [ObjectPath: /com/canonical/menu/2E00004]],
[Argument: (uso) 55244411, ":1.114", [ObjectPath: /com/canonical/menu/34AF67B]],
[Argument: (uso) 55370996, ":1.114", [ObjectPath: /com/canonical/menu/34CE4F4]],
         ...
[Argument: (uso) 65083174, ":1.275", [ObjectPath: /com/canonical/menu/3E11726]],
[Argument: (uso) 65085474, ":1.275", [ObjectPath: /com/canonical/menu/3E12022]],
```

Examining

```
qdbus --session  com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar /com/canonical/AppMenu/Registrar
```

it may be these methods are useful:

```
method void org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set(QString interface_name, QString property_name, QDBusVariant value
method void com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar.RegisterWindow(uint windowId, QDBusObjectPath menuObjectPath)
method void com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar.UnregisterWindow(uint windowId)
```

Note the parameter identified as `menuObjectPath`. These method names are qualified 
with `{un}RegisterWindow`, so the methods perhaps are irrelevant to indicator menues.

Once the correct methods with their parameters are identified it is easier to use `qdbus` (cannot use QVariant parameters however) or `D-Feet` than `gdbus` to invoke the methods.

Basically `qdbus` and `gdbus` are functionally the same and use identical parameters except:

- `qdbus` does not identify the separate components with `--dest, --object-path, --method, ...` but instead requires the corresponding attributes be given in exact order
- `gdbus` method calls handle more parameter types
- `qdbus` is not as exhaustive as`gdbus` especially w/ `--recurse`
- `qdbus` can expediently extract its command parameter sequence via double or triple click from its output w/ a middle click to concatenate it to the end of the command

The answer
[How does one find out which application is associated with an indicator icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185991/how-does-one-find-out-which-application-is-associated-with-an-indicator-icon/187226#187226)
in the post mentioned above describes how to use `qdbus` as an expedient technique to compose the scripts.

The manpage `man gdbus` (or [`gdbus:`](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.32/gdbus.html)) has a better exposition than `man qdbus` but consider `D-Feet`.